# .getValue() take too long in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few cells that take a long time to get value. I often have `getValues()` that's much faster, only some dozen milliseconds. Is this a problem with the cell or that's just how slow the function is? What's the reason for this slowness? There are many more `getValue()` call in my script but none of them take more than 400 milliseconds. Many time I run, just these 2 cells is very slow to get value.

```
//Original issue
[19-11-11 19:05:16:980 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A13]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:286 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [2.306 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:373 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([F1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:326 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [3.952 seconds]
```

This is the code

```
//This function put data from a key sheet into a database sheet. 
function enterTransDatabase_()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetLocation = ss.getSheetByName('DefaultValues');

//This get the location of data in the key sheet and database field and match them
var dBField = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('A26:A54').getValues());
var keySummary = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('B26:B54').getValues());
var keyDataLocation = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('C26:C54').getValues());
var numberFormat = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('D26:D54').getValues());

var sheetKey = ss.getSheetByName('Data_entry');
var sheetDB = ss.getSheetByName('Trans_DB_Temp');
var lastRow = sheetDB.getLastRow();
var transLines = Math.max(sheetKey.getRange('J10').getValue(),1);
var nextSTT = ss.getSheetByName('DefaultValues').getRange('G2').getValue();
var beginTransRow; 
var maxSearchRow = 20;
var searchColumn = 7;
var formatArray = []
var dataRange = []


//Create numbering for data entries
var sttColumn = []
for (var i1 = 0; i1<transLines;i1++)
{
  sttColumn.push([nextSTT + i1])
}
sheetDB.getRange(lastRow+1, 1,transLines,1).setValues(sttColumn);

for (var iR=0; iR<transLines;iR++)
{
var copyArray = []
formatArray.push(numberFormat)
for (var iC =0; iC<dBField.length;iC++)
{
  if(keySummary[iC]==1)
  {
    if (keyDataLocation[iC] == 'D10')
    {copyArray[iC] = sheetKey.getRange(keyDataLocation[iC]).getDisplayValue();}
    else
    {copyArray[iC] = sheetKey.getRange(keyDataLocation[iC]).getValue();}
  }
  else if (keySummary[iC]==0)
  {
    copyArray[iC] = sheetKey.getRange(14 + iR,keyDataLocation[iC]).getValue();
  }
  else if (keySummary[iC]===2)     
  {
    if (dBField[iC]==='Time used')   
    {copyArray[iC] = Math.round((sheetKey.getRange('V14').getValue() - sheetKey.getRange('V9').getValue())/1000/transLines)}
    else if (dBField[iC]==='IsCurrent')   
    {copyArray[iC] = 1}
    else if (dBField[iC]==='STT dòng')   
    {copyArray[iC] = iR + 1}
    else if (dBField[iC]==='ID dòng')   
    {copyArray[iC] = (10000 + copyArray[26]*1)*1000 + copyArray[27]}
  }
}
dataRange.push(copyArray)
}
sheetDB.getRange(lastRow+1, 2, transLines, dBField.length).setNumberFormats(formatArray)
sheetDB.getRange(lastRow+1, 2, transLines, dBField.length).setValues(dataRange)
sheetDB.getRange(lastRow+1, 34, transLines, 1).setValue('Cell G6 in Default')
KeyUpdate()
return true;
}
```

This is the execution log.

```
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:830 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:832 ICT] Starting execution
[19-11-11 19:05:10:845 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:846 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:903 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getName() [0.056 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:904 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:904 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:904 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:904 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:904 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:905 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:906 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:10:907 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:193 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.285 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:194 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:300 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.105 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:302 ICT] Logger.log([Start checking, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:303 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:303 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Data_entry]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:304 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:304 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:305 ICT] Logger.log([5.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:305 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 4]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:305 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:306 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 5]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:306 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:307 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 6]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:307 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:307 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:308 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:308 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:308 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getA1Notation() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:309 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:441 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0.131 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:441 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:442 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:442 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:442 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:443 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:444 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:444 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:445 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:445 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:445 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:446 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D11]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:446 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:446 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:447 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:447 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:447 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:447 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:448 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:448 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:448 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:448 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:449 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:449 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([E14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:449 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:449 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:450 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([F14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:450 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:450 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:451 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([G14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:451 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:451 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:452 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([H14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:452 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.isBlank() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:452 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:452 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:453 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([DefaultValues]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:454 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A26:A54]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:596 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0.142 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:598 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B26:B54]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:598 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:599 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([C26:C54]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:599 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:600 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D26:D54]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:601 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:602 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Data_entry]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:602 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Trans_DB_Temp]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:785 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getLastRow() [0.182 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:786 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:787 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:787 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([DefaultValues]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:788 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([G2]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:906 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.117 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:11:907 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([1, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:089 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.181 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:090 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([2, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:090 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:091 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([3, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:091 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:092 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([4, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:092 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:092 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([5, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:092 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:093 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([6, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:093 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:094 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([7, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:094 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:094 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([8, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:094 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:095 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([9, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:095 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:096 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([10, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:096 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:096 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([11, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:096 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:097 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([12, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:097 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:098 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([13, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:098 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:098 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:098 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([750, 1, 1, 1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:372 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues([[[750.0]]]) [0.273 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:12:373 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([F1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:326 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [3.952 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:326 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:486 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getDisplayValue() [0.159 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:487 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:487 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:488 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:645 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0.157 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:647 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:782 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0.135 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:784 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D11]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:784 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:785 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:785 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:786 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:786 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:787 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A101]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:961 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0.173 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:962 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 4]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:962 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:963 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:963 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:964 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 5]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:964 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:964 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 6]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:964 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:965 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:965 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:965 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:966 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:966 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:966 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:967 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A101]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:967 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:967 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([14, 10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:968 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:968 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J11]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:968 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:969 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:969 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:969 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([Q1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:969 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:970 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:970 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:971 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V2]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:971 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:971 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V3]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:971 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:972 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:972 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:973 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:973 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:973 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:973 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:974 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([750, 2, 1, 29]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:975 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setNumberFormats([[[@, dd/mm/yyyy, @, @, @, @, #,##0, @, @, @, @, @, #,##0.00, #,##0.00, #,##0.00, #0%, @, #,##0, #,##0, #,##0, @, @, @, dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, #,##0, #,##0, #,##0, #,##0, #,##0]]]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:975 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([750, 2, 1, 29]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:976 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues([[[Gokids Việt Nam, 15/8/19, HĐ VAT, Hoa Tươi- Quà Tặng& Trái Cây Yến Nhi, 0314804996, 03CB/18P, 26230.0, Mua, , Hoa tươi, , bó, 1.0, 700000.0, 700000.0, K, , 700000.0, 700000.0, 700000.0, 910_IBS_new...) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:977 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([750, 34, 1, 1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:977 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([Cell G6 in Default]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:977 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:978 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Data_entry]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:978 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V3]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:979 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([Mon Nov 11 19:05:16 GMT+07:00 2019]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:16:980 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A13]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:286 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [2.306 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:287 ICT] Logger.log([Starting cleaning up sheet, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:288 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:289 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([DefaultValues]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:289 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A2:A22]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:390 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0.1 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:391 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B2:B22]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:391 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:392 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([C2:C22]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:393 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:394 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:395 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Data_entry]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:395 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([K1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:522 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.126 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:523 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:525 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:525 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:526 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([Mon Nov 11 19:05:18 GMT+07:00 2019]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:526 ICT] Logger.log([started cleaning , []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:527 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D8:D11]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:528 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setNumberFormat([@]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:528 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([L14:L100]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:720 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear([{contentsOnly=true}]) [0.191 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:721 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D1:E1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:948 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear([{contentsOnly=true}]) [0.226 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:19:949 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:024 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([false]) [0.074 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:025 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:026 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=iferror(VLOOKUP($E$1;$A$2:$B$6;2;0);"Phải điền")]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:026 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:027 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(or(D7="Phải điền";NOT(ISFORMULA(D7)));"Phải điền";if(isnumber(E1);index(D2:D6;E1;1);IFERROR(vlookup(D7; MST_DB_All!D2:F;2;0); iferror(getAddrFromMST(D7;0);"Phải điền"))))]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:028 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D9]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:028 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=IF(MID(Q1;6;1)="S";"Bán";"Mua")]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:029 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D10:D12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:255 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear([{contentsOnly=true}]) [0.225 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:256 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([I14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:320 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(or(D14="";$J$7="Tờ khai");"";G14*F14)]) [0.064 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:321 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:322 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(D14="";"";(iferror(--H14;0)+1)*if($J$7="Tờ khai";G14;I14))]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:323 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J7]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:323 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=VLOOKUP(mid(Q1;5;3);DefaultValues!$M$1:$N$5;2;0)]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:324 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J8]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:325 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:325 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A14:H100]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:761 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear([{contentsOnly=true}]) [0.436 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:763 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([I15:K100]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:914 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear([{contentsOnly=true}]) [0.151 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:915 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([K14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:979 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([false]) [0.064 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:980 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:981 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(and(left($D$2;5)="Không";$J$8<>"");"Phải điền";if(isblank(C14);""; INDEX($D$2:$D$6;C14;1)))]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:981 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V10]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:982 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A14]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:982 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo([Range, PASTE_FORMULA, false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:20:983 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:347 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.363 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:348 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([J1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:349 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([377.0]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:350 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([F1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:350 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=vlookup(VLOOKUP($J$1;File_list!$A$2:$F;2;0);ClientDB!$C$2:$D;2;0)]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:351 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B2]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:351 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(V12="";"";if(V11="SP"; iferror(query(Goods_DB_All!A2:D;" Select B where lower(D) contains '"&$V$12&"' and B contains '"&$F$1&"' limit 5");"Không có kết quả");iferror(query(MST_DB_All!A2:I;" Selec...) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:352 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D2]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:352 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([=if(V12="";"";if(V11="SP"; iferror(query(Goods_DB_All!A2:D;" Select C where lower(D) contains '"&$V$12&"' and B contains '"&$F$1&"' limit 5");"Không có kết quả trong cơ sở dữ liệu, hãy nhập mới");ife...) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:353 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([17, 2, 100, 11]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:354 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBackground([null]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:354 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B7:J12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:355 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBorder([false, false, false, false, false, false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:355 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B14:L100]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:356 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBorder([false, false, false, false, false, false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:21:356 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([D14:D100]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:086 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [4.729 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:087 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B14:L16]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:089 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBorder([true, true, true, true, false, false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:089 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([B7:J12]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:090 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBorder([true, true, true, true, false, false]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:091 ICT] Logger.log([Done resetting cells, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:091 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:092 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Data_entry]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:093 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([V1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:407 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.313 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:26:559 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getImages() [0.152 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:31:400 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.replace([https://drive.google.com/a/tsas.vn/uc?id=1knpfbX7k7TSDi2hQZ4lTheLBJ641Xvce&export=download]) [4.84 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:31:401 ICT] Logger.log([Replacing done, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:020 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.getHeight() [0.118 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:021 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.getWidth() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:022 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([O1]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:112 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue() [0.089 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:113 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.setWidth([600]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:490 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.setHeight([849]) [0.377 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:491 ICT] Logger.log([resize done, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:492 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([1, 4]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:492 ICT] SpreadsheetApp.Range.activate() [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:493 ICT] Logger.log([Clean sheet done, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-11-11 19:05:33:920 ICT] Execution succeeded [22.649 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: F1: `=vlookup(VLOOKUP($J$1;File_list!$A$2:$F;2;0);ClientDB!$C$2:$D;2;0)`. A13: `=COUNTIFS(A14:A100;False;K14:K100;True)`. Those are the functions in the cells.

Comment: How many rowsand columns per sheet? Delete empty rows and columns. `getValue()` is slow because your sheet is big.

Comment: @TheMaster the `File_list` sheet is 300 rows, `ClientDB` is about 40 rows. The biggest sheet in this file is about 500 rows and 30 columns but it is not related to those 2 cells in anyway.

Comment: It might take 3 seconds rarely( especially on a cold start). Does it always take 3 seconds?

Comment: I just add the final answer. At the end, I move the operations around so it doesn't `setValue` and `getValue` between different sheets. It saves 8-10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trial, I have found the cause of the slowness. It turns out that whenever you switch sheet form another sheet that you just `setValue` to `getValue`, it takes a long time. From my experiments, only `setValue` will constitute "set sheet as current" AND only `getValue` will constitute "switching sheet". Other functions like `getRange`, `getSheetByName`,`isBlank`(need recheck),`getLastRow` does not have the same effect. It doesn't matter if the sheet is loaded in memory or not. It doesn't matter the function is `getValue` or `getValues`. Other actions doesn't seem to matter. For example

```
var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName('A');
var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName('B');
var cell1 = sheetA.getRange(1,1)
cell1.setValue('ABC')//"current sheet" is now sheet A
var something = sheetA.getRange(1,1).getValue()//Same sheet as last setValue=>Fast
//[most other operations doesn't involve getValue in another sheet] //Fast
var cell2 = sheetB.getRange(1,1)//getRange from other sheet is not affected =>fast
cell1.setValue('CDE')//setValue is not "switching sheet" => fast 
cell1.setValue('GHK')//"current sheet" is now sheet A
var value2 = cell2.getValue() //<= getValue in sheet B. Slow, at least 2-3000 milliseconds.
```

- So if it's possible and you care about seconds of reaction time, you should minimize switching sheet when `setValue` and `getValue`
- Also, if you work between 3 sheets in an operation, it's guaranteed that operation would take at least 4-6 seconds.

Comment: I suspect that when switching sheets, the Apps Service flushes the caches used for optimization described in [the best practices document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Comment: @chuckx I don't really know enough under-the-hood operation of Google script to add a meaningful insight. I can only report my findings. It seems unproductive to me to flush it before the script complete operations. On big operation (30 seconds) that add 10%, on small operation (<5) that adds at least 50% calculation time at a cost of a few(maybe 100) KB of ram. But maybe they have to do it to because it's better for calculation/memory in a huge scale.

Comment: I added more clarification. Strangely enough, a) `setValue` in A then `setValue` in B is NOT "switching sheet".
b)`getValue` in A then `getValue` in B is NOT "switching sheet".
c)`getValue` in A then `setValue` in B is NOT "switching sheet".
Seems quite unusual, like a bug to me.

Comment: @TamLe Thanks for this answer. I must add that `getRange` doesn't really do anything server-side as far as I know (it doesn't need to get any data) - or maybe just checks the metadata. `getSheetByName` definitely just checks the sheet's  metadata. Are you sure that `isBlank` does not behave as `getValue` does?

Comment: I could get `isBlank` wrong. It was thousand lines of log. As I don't have time to re-check it, I will edit it from my answer. Anyone have time can test it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Making repeated calls to the Apps Script API can significantly slow a script down, as you've observed. You should design your script to minimize the number of API calls made.

The [best practices documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) specifically calls this out:

> Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script,
>   read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations
>   on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.

The example provided in the documentation depicts a scenario where a 70x performance improvement is achieved. Your code suffers from the same issue as the example (i.e. performing API calls within nested loops).

Here's a simple, obvious example from the beginning of your script:

```
var dBField = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('A26:A54').getValues());
var keySummary = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('B26:B54').getValues());
var keyDataLocation = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('C26:C54').getValues());
var numberFormat = convert2SingleArray(sheetLocation.getRange('D26:D54').getValues());
```

Instead of repeatedly calling `getRange()` to capture adjacent sets of data, this could instead be handled with a single `getRange()` call:

```
var sheetLocationValues = sheetLocation.getRange('A26:D54').getValues();
var transposedSheetLocationValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheetLocationValues[0].length; i++) {
    transposedSheetLocationValues[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < sheetLocationValues.length; j++) {
        transposedSheetLocationValues[i][j] = sheetLocationValues[j][i]
    }
}
var dbField = transposedSheetLocationValues[0];
var keySummary = transposedSheetLocationValues[1];
var keyDataLocation = transposedSheetLocationValues[2];
var numberFormat = transposedSheetLocationValues[4];
```

Your execution transcript depicts a huge repetition of `getValue()` and `getRange()` calls.

You should instead ingest the entire range of data you're interested in before you enter the loops. Then process the data in memory without making API calls. When you're done, write the resultant data using as few API calls as possible.

Comment: The code's improvement is certainly welcome, however, this do not address my question. The problem is sometimes 1 single `getValue` call takes up to 3-4 seconds. I need to know if that's normal or there is a reason to it.

Comment: Also, the array `dbField` and other  you get is not correct. The array `sheetLocationValues` must be transposed before getting values.

Comment: Good point, now I see what `convert2SingleArray()` is doing. Updated the example to transpose the 2-dimensional array before extracting the rows.

Comment: I think you should also add comment in code to show why the data must be transposed. That way when new comer they copy the code they would know why that block is there.